# Calling ThingsBoard REST API through Python3

Tags: python-3.x, thingsboard

I try to access ThingsBoard over the Swagger REST API. I want to create and read out the credentials of a device. But I struggle with the usage of the `get_tenant_device` call. Please take a look at the following example.

```
from tb_rest_client.rest_client_pe import *
from tb_rest_client.rest import ApiException

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    with RestClientPE(base_url = URL) as rest_client:
        try:
            rest_client.login(username = USERNAME, password = PASSWORD)

            device = Device(name="WaterMeter1", type="waterMeter")
            rest_client.save_device(device)
            print(type(device))
            A = rest_client.get_tenant_device("WaterMeter1")
            print(type(A))

        except ApiException as e:
            print(e)
```

The device `WaterMeter1` is created, but I get an `AttributeError` type for the return value of `get_tenant_device` (but an Exception isn´t triggered!):

```
<class 'tb_rest_client.models.models_pe.device.Device'>
<class 'AttributeError'>
```

What´s the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The REST client is currently designed to work with TB3.3.1

If your Thingsboard deployment is not also at version 3.3.1 then you will occasionally run into AttributeError.

If you just purely use the Swagger api you will not get this error.